# Eclipse debugger for a domain specific language

Tags: eclipse

I am thinking of developing a debugger for a XML based programming language. The execution engine for this language is written in Java and invoked always as part of a Java application. The execution engine maintains information for execution stack, line numbers etc., for code written using this language. I am wondering about the best way to go about writing a debugger. Is there a way to piggy back on Eclipse's Java debugger or should this be a totally new debugger?

Comment: Look into [DLTK](https://www.eclipse.org/dltk/) - a framework for language support

Comment: Thanks Basilevs, DLTK does look promising for the Editor part of the requirement. But, it does not seem to have anything to help with writing a new / extending an existing eclipse debugger.